# Still gpsd drains battery on galaxy

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, battery, gps

There are a lot of questions about **gpsd drains the battery on Samsung Galaxy noteIII**. Most of them, including the official gpsd [page](http://www.catb.org/gpsd/faq.html#android), says that it is actually another application which uses gpsd and that is the problem not gpsd itself...

Now the question, how can I find which application uses gps daemon? I know the famous ones are maps, camera. However, I am looking for other applications.

As discussed [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8900/whats-using-my-gps), [Spare Parts+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.droidgram.spareparts) should do such thing, but it doesn't work on galaxy (see its related comment with reputations). I also tried Gsam. All it shows is that`/system/bin/gpsd` is being in used!!

It is really annoying... How can I find who is using `/system/bin/gpsd`

????!!!!!

Comment: As that's usually done via location services, you can watch out for related wakelocks. See [How to deal with (orphaned) WakeLocks?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/34969/16575#34972) There's a section dealing with that.